# How does Google implement Microsoft Exchange access?

Tags: android, web-services, soap, exchange-server

I know with Android 2.x there is the ability to tap into Microsoft Exchange, for at least email, if not calendar and contacts.  I would like to see how this was accomplished.  Particularly because Microsoft Exchange exposes SOAP web services, and I understand there is no native Android support for SOAP.  Since this is open source, shouldn't I be able to find something in the Android source?  If so, can you point me in the right direction of where to find it in the ~4Gig (!) source?  I want to develop an application that accesses Exchange contacts and calendars, but don't want to reinvent that piece. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Android 2.2 (Froyo) has full exchange "push" support including contact and calendar sync.  However the 2.2 source has not yet been published by google so you won't be able to investigate the source yet.  When it is released you can find it at https://android.googlesource.com

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use SOAP from android KSoap2 library is working ok.

http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/